# How to save gif added image to camera roll?

Tags: swift, gif, sdwebimage

I have an image view image. I am opening up Giphy SDK bottom sheet to add gif on my already added image.

I create gif view to add on already added image using this code:

```
private func createGifView(url: String?) {
        let x = CGFloat.random(in: 0...(parentView.frame.width - 80))
        let y = CGFloat.random(in: 0...(parentView.frame.height - 80))
        let imageView = SDAnimatedImageView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 120, height: 120))
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        if let url = url {
            imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url), completed: nil)
        }
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(emojiDidMove))
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(emojiDidPinch))
        let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(emojiDidRotate))
        panGesture.delegate = self
        pinchGesture.delegate = self
        rotationGesture.delegate = self
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
        parentView.addSubview(imageView)
        guard let rightBarButtonItems = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems else { return }
        rightBarButtonItems[1].isEnabled = true
    }
```

I try this code to save gif added image to camera roll:

```
private func saveEmojiAddedImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(parentView.frame.size)
        parentView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return UIImage(named: "smile")! }

        let imageView = SDAnimatedImageView()
        let animatedImage = SDAnimatedImage(named: "image.gif")
        imageView.image = animatedImage

        imageView.image = image

        let imageData = imageView.image?.sd_imageData(as: .GIF)
        if let data = imageData {
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset().addResource(with: .photo, data: data, options: nil)
        }) { success, error in
            guard success else {
                print("failed to save gif \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            print("successfully saved gif")
        }
        }

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return image

    }
```

I am obtaining giphy gif using this function:

```
extension MainViewController: GiphyDelegate {
    func didSelectMedia(giphyViewController: GiphyViewController, media: GPHMedia) {
        let url = media.url(rendition: .fixedWidth, fileType: .gif)
        createGifView(url: url)
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it saving it as an image, or what is the issue?

Comment: It is saving as an image. I want to save like instagram story gif added image. For example if you add image to your story and you can add gif on your image and you can save this gif added image to your camera roll. One static image and on dynamic animated gif on your static image

Comment: Is `image.gif` local? Or are you selecting a `.gif` from GIPHY? If so, could you please show how you are obtaining your gif

Comment: I am selecting a .gif from GIPHY. I edited my code to show how I am obtaining my gif.

Comment: I'm not sure that the quesiton you're asking is?  What happens that you don't expect?

Comment: Final image must be static image + gif = static bg image concluded with gif. My problem is it is saving only as an static image with static gif image. Gif is not animating in final picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem taking 25 screenshots of gif added imageview using Timer. I added these 25 screenshots to UIImage array and convert it to them video, finally saved to the photo library as a video.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
  private var gifImages: [UIImage] = []
  private var gifTimer: Timer?

  UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save,
                            target: self,
                            action: #selector(fireTimer))

 @objc func fireTimer() {
        scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()
    }

 private func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
        gifTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(saveEmojiAddedImage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   }

  //MARK: - SaveEmojiAddedImage
  //Final Image
  @objc private func saveEmojiAddedImage() {
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(parentView.frame.size, true, 0.0)
       parentView.drawHierarchy(in: parentView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)            guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        if isGIFAdded {
            self.gifImages.append(image)
            indicator.startAnimating()
            view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            print("Gif Images Count: \(gifImages.count)")
            if gifImages.count == 25 {
                self.stopTimer()
                indicator.stopAnimating()
                view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }


    func stopTimer() {
        if gifTimer != nil {
            gifTimer!.invalidate()
            gifTimer = nil
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.createVideo()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Create video using 25 screenshots of imageview

```
 func createVideo()  {
  let settings = CXEImagesToVideo.videoSettings(codec: AVVideoCodecType.h264.rawValue, width: (gifImages[0].cgImage?.width)!, height: (gifImages[0].cgImage?.height)!)
  let movieMaker = CXEImagesToVideo(videoSettings: settings)
  movieMaker.createMovieFrom(images: gifImages){ (fileURL:URL) in
      if self.isSaveVideo {
         PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
         PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: fileURL)
           }) { saved, error in
                self.gifImages.removeAll()
                if saved {
                     self.gifImages.removeAll()
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.presentAlert(withTitle: "Successful", message: "GIF saved successfully")
                     }
                  } else {
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         self.presentAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: "")
                      }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                self.gifImages.removeAll()
                self.videoFileURL = fileURL
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not work on real device. I will work only in simulator.